# Code to detect Sunday to Saturday date windows and modify Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to set up a code that will take in a table with date windows and modify them to fit a Sun-Sat template.

I have the data saved as follows:

```
 Index   Name:               From:        To:    
   1      Joe Doe            6/1/2020     6/8/2020
   2      Joe Doe            6/14/2020    6/23/2020
   3      Brandon Smith      5/9/2020     5/20/2020
   4      Brandon Smith      5/26/2020    5/28/2020
   5      Brandon Smith      5/12/2020    5/24/2020
   6      Brandon Smith      5/26/2020    5/31/2020
   7      Sarah Roberts      6/3/2020     6/25/2020
   8      Sarah Roberts      6/15/2020    6/23/2020
```

I would like to create another From: and To: columns but only capturing windows of 7,14,21... days that run from a Sunday to a Saturday.

For example: Index 1 would not apply, index 2 would get transformed from the 14th to the 20th, and so forth.

The resulting table that I was hoping to get would look like this:

```
 Index   Name:               From:        To:          From_new:    To_new
   1      Joe Doe            6/1/2020     6/8/2020     NA           NA
   2      Joe Doe            6/14/2020    6/23/2020    6/12/2020    6/20/2020
   3      Brandon Smith      5/9/2020     5/20/2020    5/10/2020    5/16/2020
   4      Brandon Smith      5/26/2020    5/28/2020    NA           NA
   5      Brandon Smith      5/12/2020    5/24/2020    5/17/2020    5/23/2020
   6      Brandon Smith      5/26/2020    5/31/2020    NA           NA
   7      Sarah Roberts      6/3/2020     6/25/2020    6/7/2020     6/20/2020
   8      Sarah Roberts      6/15/2020    6/23/2020    NA           NA
```

I've tried to loop through each record and look at the start week day, if it's Sunday then run to the next Saturday, but then I get confused if it runs for another whole week after that, or if it's not Sunday to begin with.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop. The solution was in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600401/pandas-return-the-next-sunday-for-every-row). All credits should go to @ifly6. :)

Having said that, this should work for you:

```py
    df['From_new'] = df['From:'] + pd.offsets.Week(weekday=6)
    df.loc[df['From:'].dt.weekday == 6, 'From_new'] = df.loc[df['From:'].dt.weekday == 6, 'From:']
    df['To_new'] = df['To:'] - pd.offsets.Week(weekday=5)
    df.loc[df['To:'].dt.weekday == 5, 'To_new'] = df.loc[df['From:'].dt.weekday == 5, 'To:']
    df.loc[df['To_new'] < df['From_new'], 'From_new'] = pd.NaT
    df.loc[df['From_new'].isna(), 'To_new'] = pd.NaT
```

Output:

```
     Index    Name:      From:        To:   From_new     To_new
1      Joe      Doe 2020-06-01 2020-06-08        NaT        NaT
2      Joe      Doe 2020-06-14 2020-06-23 2020-06-14 2020-06-20
3  Brandon    Smith 2020-05-09 2020-05-20 2020-05-10 2020-05-16
4  Brandon    Smith 2020-05-26 2020-05-28        NaT        NaT
5  Brandon    Smith 2020-05-12 2020-05-24 2020-05-17 2020-05-23
6  Brandon    Smith 2020-05-26 2020-05-31        NaT        NaT
7    Sarah  Roberts 2020-06-03 2020-06-25 2020-06-07 2020-06-20
8    Sarah  Roberts 2020-06-15 2020-06-23        NaT        NaT
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Regarding index 2 I made a mistake but I think it should still show from 6/14 (Sun) to 6/20 (Sat)

Comment: You are right. I didn't consider the special case if it starts with a Sunday or ends with a Saturday. I have edited my answer to fix this.